# Include Jsfiddle doppelgängers in the filter or change the suggestion?

Tags: feature-request

Currently, when asking a question regarding web development, linking to [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) without adding any code into the question itself produces the following just-in-time warning:

[image: Sample image]

Even though SO now features built-in fiddling capabilities, many people, for one reason or another, still decide to use external sites like:

- [Codepen](http://codepen.io/)
- [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)

Would it be possible to include the following sites in the above filter?

Alternatively, wouldn't it be more reasonable to change the above warning to suggest the on-site fiddling tool?

Comment: Why alternatively instead of in addition? Though beware, some code might actually work on jsfiddle or the like, but not in a stack-snippet, due to the sandboxing.

Comment: Then they'll just switch to [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) or the nth other similar service that isn't yet blacklisted.

Comment: @cvrebert The aim isn't to blacklist the sites.  It's to provide a helpful tip to new users about what SO expects in an answer.

Answer (score -4):

Stack Overflow can't be expected to continue to update its code to block for every single code sandbox on the web; that is not really feasible. They simply chose one of the most popular ones when implementing the feature originally.

As an aside, I can answer the "for some reason" of your question. The reason is that it is infinitely easier to iterate over existing code or create new code snippets using services like JSFiddle, JSBin, and CodePen. As handy as StackSnippets are, they have some serious limitations.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with this necessarily...it's not an update for "every single code sandbox on the web," it's just adding another couple of major ones. The goal isn't to eliminate the practice 100% of the time, just as much of the time as possible.

Comment: @AlexK The question is (and has been asked before by moderators in similar questions/requests), where do they draw the line? In a year, JSFiddle and CodePen might be gone from the web, forsaken for some new, flavor-of-the-week site. Unfortunately I'm not part of the Stack Overflow development team so I can't speak as an original source for them. I wish I could find where they've answered it before, because I know they have.